# Public folders report script - Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, directory, public, exchange-server-2010

Can any of you help me with a PowerShell script to get all public folders and for each of them to show who has access?

What I have so far is this:

```
Get-PublicFolder -Identity "\" -Recurse | select Name,Identity,HasSubFolders,HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled | Export-Csv "C:\PFReport.csv"
```

I know that I need a for each loop, and query the CSV instead of storing it directly into a variable, but I do not know how to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Why would you need to query the csv instead of a variable? You could save the output to a variable, iterate through it and still export it to csv later on. Take a look at the `Get-Acl` Commandlet to look for access rights.

Comment: If I would store that info into a variable it may take ages because I have to iterate through over 20k of PFs.